# Getting the elements’ indexes when iterating over an array with for-of

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript, you can iterate over an array with `for-of` (this is an ES6 feature):

```
let arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

for (let elem of arr) {
  // elem = current element
}
```

But sometimes, the corresponding element index is also needed in the loop; one approach is to explicitly use the `entries` iterator like so:

```
for (let [i, elem] of arr.entries()) {
  // elem = current element
  // i = current index
}
```

Now, maybe it’s just me, but that `.entries()` part makes this pattern a bit messy and less readable, so I made `entries` the default iterator of `arr`:

```
arr[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype.entries;
```

and now I can leave it out:

```
for (let [i, elem] of arr) {
  // elem = current element
  // i = current index
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsbin.com/gateva/edit?js,console

However, I haven’t figured out how to apply this “hack” to all arrays (i.e. make it the global default). Is that possible and does it have any side effects or downsides (other than having to always specify `i`, even if you don’t use it, which would be a problem for linters, I guess)?

Comment: If you're worried about linters, jshint supports `// jshint esnext: true` at the top of the file.

Comment: Not certain what requirement is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own class that extends native `Array`, and change its default iterator to `Array.prototype.entries`:

```
class MyArray extends Array {}
MyArray.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype.entries
```

Then you create a new instance of MyArray like that:

```
const arr = new MyArray(1, 2, 3)
```

And iterate it like that:

```
for (let [i, elem] of arr) {
  console.log(`Element ${elem} at index ${i}`)
}
```

See [JS Bin demo](https://jsbin.com/muwece/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: Note: I thought that changing the default iterator of `Array` (i.e. `Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype.entries`) would be enough, but there are some weird issues with that. Anyway, modifying native objects is not a good idea.

Comment: I’ve tried setting `Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` but I got incorrect output (see the demo in my comment to the other answer).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes, that's why you should create your own class.

Comment: @Šime You can subclass `Array` in ES2015, so there's really no longer a reason (if ever) to modify the built-in prototype